# Can't install linux on old Asus A2H

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bootable-media, lubuntu

I found an old Asus A2h laptop and I wish to install Lubuntu 16.04 LTS 32bit  on it.
I tried everything to get my work done; when trying to boot from usb I get this:

```
DISK BOOT FAILURE: INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER
```

when trying to boot from a working dvd image nothing happens (the disk seems not to be read, the only character on the screen is a flashing underscore)

I am sure that the USB slot, the USB stick, the iso Cd and the dvd reader work properly (I tried USB and cd on other pcs and I recently installed win xp sp2 using the cd installer).

I also tried every possible combination of BIOS options (an old AwarsBIOS) but no way. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: (1) Make sure it has a DVD drive. A google search showed that it had a optional CD-ROM drive. (2) If it really has a working DVD drive then make sure the Ubuntu DVD was burned correctly (image to disk). (3) If it boots from external USB devices prefer that anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. 1) The DVD drive works, I used it to install win xp; 2) the disk had been burned correctly, I ran it on another pc and checked the structure of the filetree. 3) I tried to boot from different USB devices and with different images but the error page is always the same

Comment: (1) XP installation is by CD, not DVD. You can't infer from that that you have a DVD drive and even if you have it can be defective, ie, CDs may work but not DVDs (different lasers). Have you tried booting from that DVD in other computers? How have you prepared the USB sticks you tried?

Comment: Ok @GabrielaGarcia , got it, spent about an hour trying to update the drivers (visited https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/asus/laptops-desktops/a2h-l/8523) but they did not solve my problem, still stuck :(

Comment: Updating drivers for what? Whether the optical driver supports DVD or not has nothing to do with drivers. Whether or not it can boot from a USB stick or that USB has been correctly done has nothing to do with drivers. Whether or not the DVD was correctly burned has nothing to do with drivers. So, not entirely unexpected, the fact of the matter here is you really don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Damn, you're right, what a blunder! However, I flashed the USB sticks first using Etcher (that I always used without problems) and then trying UNetbootin. Instead, I burned the ISO image to the cd simply using win 10. Thansk for your patience @Gabriela

Comment: You must have burned it to a DVD because it doesn't fit a CD and it's important to check which options. In Windows the way to do it is: **Right-click on the ISO file and select "Burn disk image."** Any other option will NOT result in a bootable DVD. Then you need to make sure that you have a working DVD drive in the machine you want it to boot (as commented several times above). Etcher or Unetbootin should be fine but I use neither. Anyway there's a chance old machines can't boot from USB even if properly burned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**: the pc is unable to boot from USB or DVD, but it can load **CDs**.

Reached to install ubuntu (but you can choose from several other distribution) using NetbootCD https://netbootcd.us/. Internet connection is required.